# Plot scatter graph in Excel graph with 3 variables in 2D

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

3 Columns of Data:

1. Date (from 1st till 31st)
2. Variable 1
3. variable 2

I want to make a simple graph where Variable 1 range is X axis and Variable 2 range is Y axis, 
I plot the date on the graph so: you have numbers plotted on the chart from 1 to 31 where for each plotted number you can read value of Var 1 and 2 on that day by looking down and left respectively.

How trivial yet how painful (shameful maybe) that I cannot make this simple chart in Excel

Going nuts, please assist step for step ... Thank you

Comment: Did my answer help you with your question? If not, could you please provide some additional guidance to better answer it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Excel!!!  In fact, there are at least two ways to create a chart like this:

[image: Scatter Plot with Date Variable]

The first method is easiest, but requires a free add-in (that every Excel user probably should have anyway), [Rob Bovey's XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm).

1. Set up your data (as described).
2. Add your data as a single Scatter (XY) data series.
3. Use XY Chart Labeler (its awesome) to Add Labels to your data series, using the Date data column (formatted to just days [dd] in this sample), located above your data point.
4. Format everything to your taste.

Otherwise, you can do it this way.

1. Set up your data (as described).
2. Add your data as one Scatter (XY) data series for every row in your data (one per day, in this sample).  So, if you have 31 days, you'll have 31 series.
3. Add your data labels using the data points name, located above your data point.
4. Format everything to your taste (including all 31 data series and their labels).

I'd strongly recommend the first method, or using VBA to expedite the second.

Comment: Excel 2013 has FINALLY added the ability to apply data labels to plotted points, taking the labels from a range in the worksheet. It works much like Bovey's add-in.